# Unable to login facebook with php sdk in Ios Chrome

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I am having an issue on getting my user logged into my website with facebook login in IOS chrome. I have used PHP sdk for this. Here is what I have tried

```
$facebook = new facebook(array(
              'appId' => JB_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
              'secret' => JB_FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
          ));

          $facebook->destroySession();
          $fbUser = $facebook->getUser();
          $userInfo = array();

          if ($fbUser) {
              try {
                  $userInfo = $facebook->api('/me');  
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                  $facebook->destroySession();
                  $fbUser = null;
              }
          }


          if ($fbUser) {
              $arrUserInfo['email'] = $userInfo['email'];
              $arrUserInfo['first_name'] = $userInfo['first_name'];
              $arrUserInfo['last_name'] = $userInfo['last_name'];
              $arrUserInfo['gender'] = $userInfo['gender'];
              $arrUserInfo['birthday'] = $userInfo['birthday'];
              $arrUserInfo['city'] = isset($userInfo['location']['name']) ? $userInfo['location']['name'] : '';
              $arrUserInfo['relationship_status'] = isset($userInfo['relationship_status']) ? $userInfo['relationship_status'] : '';
              $arrUserInfo['education_json'] = isset($userInfo['education']) ? json_encode($userInfo['education']) : '';
              $arrUserInfo['employment_json'] = isset($userInfo['work']) ? json_encode($userInfo['work']) : '';
              $arrUserInfo['facebook_uid'] = $userInfo['id'];
              $userName = isset($userInfo['username']) ? $userInfo['username'] : $userInfo['id'];
              $arrUserInfo['facebook_pic_url'] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userName . '/picture?type=large';
              $urlParts = parse_url(Yii::app()->request->getUrlReferrer());
              $arrUserInfo['request_url'] = $urlParts['path'];
              $arrUserInfo['is_confirmed'] = 1;              
              $this->actionFacebookConnect($arrUserInfo);
          } else {
              $facebook->destroySession();
              $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                  array(
                      'redirect_uri' => JB_FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI,
                      'scope' => 'email, user_birthday, user_relationships, user_location, user_work_history, user_education_history',
                  )
              );
              echo '<script>window.location="' . $loginUrl . '"</script>';
          }
```

It is working on all browser but in Ios chrome I am having an error, **unsupported browser**. For my curiosity i tested Flipkart.com Facebook login and its working fine in IOS chrome.

PS: What I noticed in case of flipkart.com that its login url is bit different **"https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxx&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.flipkart.com%252Fsc%252FfbLogin%253Frd%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.flipkart.com%25252Faccount%25252Flogin%25253Ffrom%25253Dheader%26state%3DV2e220ecfd052078c6c98bf9e0b9c63f78d1t10OYjlXz1YE%252BsMmsnhXz7IPigeARiPIz3c%252FMFTrtzDyKXccl5lZHquzoMaBmanIA2dP6DEcaIQpCowvly2RVr7iMyqE8hmO5Ky4Q4fiDDdbWdOkRkxIj9%252FkLH9XnaaANj%252FbMyybuV8gyNCKkGh%252FOs3BvZZZbVq%252Fppmsm90hFuFWaWzZa0TBu6toT2DQlIC81CoYvAdHkwPRm%252BppjFDv7CodbPC8VAqYPOxOFf63BSEjuhx3aYxopflseGyE2ClPnBR59L3kqqj53XW3gpXfykMI26Pq1kfL1eQBozNJ1HFu64WvHoJPxoP8%252BFu9OjOKAtLlwrxd%252BJHVa584ItVsvUOv6ZMHZkTqdiu%252BM4hf2o7ol3Ea8cGYHGokFNJtNtWj%252B4Al5HC8LEQSAMvIhWgk%252BG9MukRZx2v5X40o9E0jqQOhLkDHa9B40Kq9mqdPrbB1jHW4Y8dFTBdJTArzuu98JMwfezRFEA3S6uN1GZEotMsSWE%253D%26scope%3Demail%26client_id%3D296559107055563%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2Fsc%2FfbLogin%3Frd%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.flipkart.com%252Faccount%252Flogin%253Ffrom%253Dheader%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3DV2e220ecfd052078c6c98bf9e0b9c63f78d1t10OYjlXz1YE%252BsMmsnhXz7IPigeARiPIz3c%252FMFTrtzDyKXccl5lZHquzoMaBmanIA2dP6DEcaIQpCowvly2RVr7iMyqE8hmO5Ky4Q4fiDDdbWdOkRkxIj9%252FkLH9XnaaANj%252FbMyybuV8gyNCKkGh%252FOs3BvZZZbVq%252Fppmsm90hFuFWaWzZa0TBu6toT2DQlIC81CoYvAdHkwPRm%252BppjFDv7CodbPC8VAqYPOxOFf63BSEjuhx3aYxopflseGyE2ClPnBR59L3kqqj53XW3gpXfykMI26Pq1kfL1eQBozNJ1HFu64WvHoJPxoP8%252BFu9OjOKAtLlwrxd%252BJHVa584ItVsvUOv6ZMHZkTqdiu%252BM4hf2o7ol3Ea8cGYHGokFNJtNtWj%252B4Al5HC8LEQSAMvIhWgk%252BG9MukRZx2v5X40o9E0jqQOhLkDHa9B40Kq9mqdPrbB1jHW4Y8dFTBdJTArzuu98JMwfezRFEA3S6uN1GZEotMsSWE%253D%23_%3D_&display=page"**

but in my case its **domain/dialog/oauth?app_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_idXXXXXXXX.....**

So my question is how I can generate url like flipkart ?